# Should I use spawn-fcgi or dotdebs php5-fpm?

Tags: 10.04, php

I am setting up an Ubuntu server with nginx, php and mysql.

I have found two options for fast-cgi php. Firstly I can use the spawn-fcgi package and make some startup scripts, similar as done [here](http://www.howtoforge.com/nginx_php5_fast_cgi_xcache_ubuntu7.04)

The second option is to use the dotdeb packages and use php5-fpm ([installation instructions](http://www.howtoforge.com/installing-php-5.3-nginx-and-php-fpm-on-ubuntu-debian))

Which one shall I choose? Are there any difference in processor usage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution that I liked better than the two mentioned ones: the php-fpm package from [Brian Mercer's ppa](https://launchpad.net/~brianmercer/+archive/php). Dotdeb's packages did not work, and the fpm package does not need any configuration scripts at all!!!

Comment: *Sorry, you don't have permission to access this page or the information in this page is not shared with you.* Any chance to find it somewhere?